# How to bind Microsoft access program with specific machine

Tags: security, ms-access

I have an access program that I need to sell to others.

Before giving the program to any body, I need to bind the version I will give to the client with his machine, in order to prevent his version from opening form any other machines.

How to perform this security issue?

Free security solutions are preferred, If not found then not free solutions.

Comment: This is really not a great question for this website, as StackExchange is really designed for people to ask *specific* questions (i.e. if you have a line of code you're having trouble with).  This one is a bit too general.

Comment: I do not need to add any code, I just asked for an MS access security issue that does not need any code.

Comment: **Exactly** why this question isn't a good fit on this website.